# How to filter specific field from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to filter only specific field not full documents from elastic search.below i have mentioned sample data for example,please check.

Ex:My data.

```
    {
  "took": 65,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 4.89784,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mytest",
        "_type": "bank",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 4.89784,
        "_source": {
          "account_number": 1,
          "balance": 39225,
          "firstname": "Amber",
          "lastname": "Duke",
          "age": 32,
          "gender": "M",
          "address": "880 Holmes Lane",
          "employer": "Pyrami",
          "email": "amberduke@pyrami.com",
          "city": "Brogan",
          "state": "IL"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Expected Result.

```
{
   [
{
"account_number": 1,
"balance": 39225,
}
   ]
}
```

my rest API

```
http://localhost:9200/mytest/bank/_search?q=firstname:Virginia%20AND%20age:39
```

Output:

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":5.882802,"hits":[{"_index":"mytest","_type":"bank","_id":"25","_score":5.882802,"_source":{"account_number":25,"balance":40540,"firstname":"Virginia","lastname":"Ayala","age":39,"gender":"F","address":"171 Putnam Avenue","employer":"Filodyne","email":"virginiaayala@filodyne.com","city":"Nicholson","state":"PA"}}]}}
```

EDIT 1

```
http://localhost:9200/mytest/bank/_search?_source=account_number&q=account_number:25
```

output:

```
{"took":7,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"mytest","_type":"bank","_id":"25","_score":1.0,"_source":{"account_number":25}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to retrieve a specific set of fields from your document ?
You can use the _source parameter like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/mytest/bank/_search?q=firstname:Virginia%20AND%20age:39&_source=account_number,balance
```

**Update**:

I will use REST API. Create the index:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test'
{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true,"index":"test"}
```

Add a document to index:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/test/1' -H'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{"one": "10", "two": "20", "three": "30", "four": "40"}'
{"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":0,"_primary_term":1}
```

Get all fields in document:

```
curl -GET 'localhost:9200/test/test/1'
{"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"one": "10", "two": "20", "three": "30", "four": "40"}}
```

Get selected fields in document:

```
curl -GET 'localhost:9200/test/test/1?_source=one,four'
{"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"four":"40","one":"10"}}
```

If you still have a problem you need to post full example as I do.

**Update 2:**

Get all fields using search request:

```
curl -XGET  -H'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:9200/test/test/_search -d'{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'
{"took":180,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{"one": "10", "two": "20", "three": "30", "four": "40"}}]}}
```

Get selected fields using search request:

```
curl -XGET  -H'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/test/test/_search?_source=one,four' -d'{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'
{"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{"four":"40","one":"10"}}]}}
```

**Update 3:**

```
curl -XGET  -H'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/test/test/_search?_source=one&q=one:10'
    {"took":11,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.2876821,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_score":0.2876821,"_source":{"one":"10"}}]}}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for response but my requirement is different please check my expected result Above.Ex.i need to remove all the field expect  account_number,balance fields.

Comment: What do you think are doing my example ? It retrieve only this two fields. Or remove all others what is the same.

Comment: i'm using REST API to call Elastic search by passing parameter, at the same time i'm using returned value to implement  to my application,But above query returned all the unwanted  value like ,"took": 65,
  "timed_out": false, etc.

Comment: Thanks for you're response,But the problem is you are passing _id=1 it will return only field related to _id field .But i need to filter entire index matching value not only specific _id block.

Comment: Just add your REST request to your question.

Comment: Look at "Update 3" section

Comment: And I have updated the first REST call to your data `http://localhost:9200/mytest/bank/_search?q=firstname:Virginia%20AND%20age:39&_source=account_number,balance`

Comment: You need to post 1) what did you do 2) what did you get

Comment: You have got only selected field `_source":{"account_number":25}`.  What is the problem ?

Comment: But i'm getting extra information like      {"took":7,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"mytest","_type":"bank","_id":"25","_score":1.0,"

Comment: Is it possible to Remove ,this is my question asking from beginning of post please check my first post..

Comment: It is not your document fields. It is a metadata. If you want to remove it you need to use `filter_path` option. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/common-options.html - look at `Response flitering` section.

Comment: Just add `&filter_path=hits.hits._source` to your URL. But `hits.hits` section remain and I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: ,Thanks for you're valuable response ,from here i will check how to  remove  hits.hits.once again thanks...